# Shouldn't we use Animated api in functional component without wrapping with useRef()?

Tags: react-native, animation, use-ref

This is how `Animated` api is declared in class component,

```
const pan = new Animated.ValueXY();
```

Where as in functional components,

```
const pan = useRef(new Animated.ValueXY()).current;
```

Source: [React-Native official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder#example)

Will there be any caveats if we use `Animated` api without wrapping with `useRef`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functional components will be called during every rendering. Without useRef. you will get a new `pan` everytime.